# Continuate test after first exception | Chai | Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, chai-http

I'm writing my unit test with an http request.
I want to test different fields in response but when I check fields in the first exception CHAI closes all, single test too. I want that CHAI continues his test execution.
How can I do this?

This is an a example how to use the expect.

`expect(res.body.data.user_data,"last_name").have.property('last_name');
expect(res.body.data.user_data.last_name,"last_name").be.a('number');`


`expect(res.body.data.user_data,"username").have.property('username');
expect(res.body.data.user_data.username,"username").be.a('string');`

Comment: what if you put it in a `try... catch` block?

Comment: you could put the expectations in separate tests

Answer (score 1):

If you surely knows that a particular statement will throws an `exception` you can use following way to test it.

```
expect(res.body.data.user_data).to.throw('Oh no')
```

Or if you want to check and handle the exception you are getting you can use `try` and `catch` block as follows:

```
try {
    expect(res.body.data.user_data, "last_name").have.property('last_name');
    expect(res.body.data.user_data.last_name, "last_name").be.a('number');
    expect(res.body.data.user_data, "username").have.property('username');
    expect(res.body.data.user_data.username, "username").be.a('string');
}
catch (e) {
    //write err and res objects to custom log file
    throw e;
}
```

I don't think its possible to continue even after the assertion failure in `Chai`.